# I need help on comparing using operators in a guessing game - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, operator-keyword

So basically, I am making a guessing game in Tkinter. I am comparing numbers to check if the number the user has guessed is greater, lesser, or the same compared to the randomly generated number. I am getting an error about my operator so please provide the correct code, thanks. Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
r = random.randint(1,100)
root.title("Game thing")
def clear():
    number_entry1.delete(0,END)
def quit():
    exit()
def Guessnumber():
    if number_entry1.get() > int(r):
        m1 = messagebox.showinfo("Sorry","Lower")
    elif number_entry1.get() < int(r):
        m2 = messagebox.showinfo("Sorry","Higher")
    else:
        m3 = messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations","You Got It!")

message_label = Label(root,text = "Guess the number form (1 - 100)")
message_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
number_entry1 = Entry(root)
number_entry1.grid(row = 0, column = 1,columnspan = 2)
guess_button = Button(root,text = "Guess Number",fg = "green",command = Guessnumber)
guess_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
clear_button = Button(root,text = "Clear",fg = "blue",command = clear)
clear_button.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
quit_button = Button(root,text = "Quit",fg = "red",command = exit)
quit_button.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = E)
```

Thanks!!! Also if you could I would like an explanation on why I am getting an error.
Again thanks for all the help everyone

Comment: What error and what operators?

Answer (score 3):

The error (which you should have provided in the question but I already detected it) is caused because You compare a string with an integer here:

```py
def Guessnumber():
    if number_entry1.get() > int(r):
        m1 = messagebox.showinfo("Sorry","Lower")
    elif number_entry1.get() < int(r):
        m2 = messagebox.showinfo("Sorry","Higher")
    else:
        m3 = messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations","You Got It!")
```

Why? because using the `.get()` method of `Entry` widgets returns the value of what was entered in the widget as a string, so the simple solution would be this:

```py
def Guessnumber():
    if int(number_entry1.get()) > int(r):
        m1 = messagebox.showinfo("Sorry","Lower")
    elif int(number_entry1.get()) < int(r):
        m2 = messagebox.showinfo("Sorry","Higher")
    else:
        m3 = messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations","You Got It!")
```

Oh, and also to mention, this is not necessary: `int(r)`, because the function `random.randint(1,100)` already returns an integer so converting it again is redundant.

And also the function `quit()` is quite useless since the only thing defined there is the built-in `exit()` which actually is the same length as in characters so kinda pointless without other functionality

The "final version" of how that function "should" (to the best practices I know) look is this (also includes some [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggestions and also that there is now only one `.get()` call which theoretically improves performance since now the method in all cases has to be called only once):

```py
def guess_number():
    user_input = int(number_entry1.get())
    if user_input > r:
        messagebox.showinfo("Sorry", "Lower")
    elif user_input < r:
        messagebox.showinfo("Sorry", "Higher")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations", "You Got It!")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought the error was that the variable r was the string. so I made that in(r). I didn't realize it was number_entry1.get(). Also I'll make sure to put the error if I have one in my question next time I post. Thanks Again!

Comment: You forgot to mention that since `messagebox.showinfo()` doesn't really return any useful information, the assignment of its return value to `m1`, `m2`, or `m3` serves no purpose.

Comment: @martineau I added a "final version" to include all the possible little improvements (that I could think of) including what you mentioned about msgboxes

Comment: Congratulations, You Got It! ;¬)

Comment: Sure thing thanks both of you